# Adding Java 2d Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need to create a method within my class to add two 2d arrays together. One is implemented as a parameter in the method, while the other is a class object. I need to make sure the arrays are the same size, and if so, add them together. I keep getting an Array Out of Bounds error. Whats wrong with my code?

```
    // method to add matrices
    public int[][] add(int[][] matrix) {
    int addedMatrices[][] = new int[row][column];
    if (userArray[row][column] == matrix[row][column]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j) {
                addedMatrices[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + userArray[i][j];
                System.out.println(addedMatrices[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return addedMatrices;
}
```

Comment: Posting the stack trace (especially the bit that tells you which line threw the exception) is very helpful. Looking at the code it looks like the `if` statement is the problem. If we had the line number then we could confirm or rule it out.

Answer (score 2):

`if (userArray[row][column] == matrix[row][column])` is the problem.

Remember that arrays are zero-indexed so the elements are numbered from zero to `row - 1`. Trying to access row `row` is guaranteed to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the last row is at index `row - 1`.

I'm not sure why you even have this line. If you change `row` to `row - 1` and `column` to `column - 1` then this line checks if the bottom-right values in the two matrices are the same. If they're not then the matrices will not be summed. Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! I revised the code to  "if (userArray == matrix) {" because I need to make sure the arrays are the same size before adding them. But, when I try to print it, only the reference to the array is printed. Do you know why?

Comment: `if (userArray == matrix)` isn't going to work either - that checks to see if `userArray` and `matrix` are references to the same object. You need to check `userArray.length` and `matrix.length`, plus the length of each row in each array. As for the printing thing, that's by design. The Array object doesn't override `toString` so it uses the default `toString` implementation. You'll need to write your own matrix-printing code or use something like Apache Commons `ArrayUtils.toString`.

Comment: I recommend java.util.Array.toString()  for the printing. +1 for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do :

```
public class Test {

    static int row =3;
    static int column =2;
    static int[][]  userArray = new int[][] {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}};

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        add(new int[][] {{4,4},{5,5},{6,6}});
    }

    // method to add matrices
    public static int[][] add(int[][] matrix) {

        int addedMatrices[][] = new int[row][column];

        //check arrays are of the same size
        if ((userArray.length == matrix.length)   &&  (userArray[0].length == matrix[0].length)  ) {

            for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {

                for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j) {
                    addedMatrices[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + userArray[i][j];

                    //printout
                    if(j == (column -1)) {
                        for(int col = 0; col < column; col++) {
                            System.out.print(addedMatrices[i][col]+ " ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
        return addedMatrices;
    }
}
```

or better:

```
public class Test {

    static int[][]  userArray = new int[][] {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}, {4,4}};

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        add(new int[][] {{5,5},{6,6},{7,7},{8,8}});
    }

    // method to add matrices
    public static int[][] add(int[][] matrix) {

        //check arrays are of the same size
        if ((userArray.length != matrix.length) ||  (userArray[0].length != matrix[0].length)  ) {

            System.out.println("Error: arrays are not of the same size");
            return null;
        }

        int rows = userArray.length;
        int cols = userArray[0].length;

        int addedMatrices[][] = new int[rows][cols];

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {

                for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {

                    addedMatrices[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + userArray[i][j];

                    //printout
                    if(j == (cols -1)) {
                        for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                            System.out.print(addedMatrices[i][col]+ " ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }

        return addedMatrices;
    }
}
```

to make the print out more elegant you could change the for loop to :

```
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {

                for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {

                    addedMatrices[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + userArray[i][j];
                }

                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(addedMatrices[i]));
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `if (userArray[row][column] == matrix[row][column]) {` should be replaced by a line to check if the dimensions of both matrices are the same (I guess that is what's intended).  Assuming they are both rectangular arrays, and non empty:

```
public class MatrixAdder {
    static public int[][] userArray =   {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

    static public int[][] add(int[][] matrix) {
        final int nb_rows1 = matrix.length;    // nb rows in matrix                                          
        final int nb_cols1 = matrix[0].length; // nb columns in matrix                                       
        final int nb_rows2 = userArray.length; // nb rows in userArray                                       
        final int nb_cols2 = userArray[0].length; // nb columns in userArray                                 
        // this assumes A[0] exists, and A[0].length == A[1].length == ...                                   
        // both for matrix and userArray                                                                     
        int addedMatrices[][] = new int[nb_rows1][nb_rows1];
        if ((nb_rows1==nb_rows2) && (nb_cols1==nb_cols2)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nb_rows1; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nb_cols1; ++j) {
                    addedMatrices[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + userArray[i][j];
                    System.out.println(addedMatrices[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return addedMatrices;
    }

    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] mx1 = {{10,100},{20,200},{40,400}};
        int [][] mx2 = add(mx1);
    }
}
```

To be more robust, you could check that the dimensions of all sub-arrays are the same.  You could also check if the matrix has zero dimension (otherwise `array[0]` will give an error).

If the dimensions are not the same, the returned matrix is filled with zeroes.

If this is not exactly what you need, it should give you enough hints.

Answer (score 0):

if (userArray[row][column] == matrix[row][column]) {}

This is strange to me, I honestly don't know what the intentions are (Your just comparing the last element of each array).

I would do 
if(addedMatrices.length == userArray.length && addedMatrices.length == matrix.length){}.

This is ugly but I don't know anything about userArray or matrix. I am presuming userArray is global. Also do j++ and i++, it has the same end result but it is more of the norm.

Comment: How is it the same thing twice, its comparing the length of addedMatrices to both userArray and Matrix. Ensuring all the arrays have the same size.